# Azure blob service, randomly 404-not found errors

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

We have a web app which processes external callbacks. To isolate our app from the external service, we use an azure blob to store the callback data (.json) and put a message to Azure Service bus for a processing service to pick up later. 
The following code is used to write the data to blob storage:

```
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("MyStorage"));
        var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("containername");
        var dataFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(dataFileName);
        blockBlob.UploadText(data);
        blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "application/json";
        blockBlob.SetProperties();

        var connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("serviceBusCS");
        var queueName = "MyQueue";
        var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);

        var payload = new MyCustomMessage {
            Id = dataFileName
        };
        var message = new BrokeredMessage(payload);
        client.Send(message);
```

On the processing side, we have a web job reading the messages *one at a time* and retrieving the data as follow:

```
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("MyCS");
            var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("containername");
            var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(message.Id);
            if (blockBlob == null) {
                return;
            }
            if (!blockBlob.Exists()) {
                return; ==> FAILS HERE
            } 
           // Process the message here...
           // Once the processing is done, delete the blob
```

This design works well most of the time but we get a 404-NotFound from now and then (marked with `FAILED HERE` above).

**QUESTION**

The only way this code can fail is by having two messages with the same file name i.e: the same GUID which is nearly impossible or am I missing something? 
Any idea why the blob data can't be found?

**EDIT 1**
Searching for the missing blob from the Azure portal shows that the blob is actually not there.
Shouldn't `blockBlob.UploadText(data);` throw if it fails to write data to the blob container?

**EDIT 2**

Thanks to Jason for indicating where to look. We crawled our logs and found that the blob is getting written successfully. The web job kicks off and processes the message but one minute later, exactly one minute later we see the web job kicking off trying to process the very same message again and it won't find the blob which is expected as the first run cleared the blob and deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

If the client application receives an HTTP 404 (Not found) message from the server, this implies that the object the client was attempting to use (such as an entity, table, blob, container, or queue) does not exist in the storage service. There are a number of possible reasons for this, such as:
•The client or another process previously deleted the object
•A Shared Access Signature (SAS) authorization issue
•Client-side JavaScript code does not have permission to access the object
•Network failure

See [Storage Monitoring, Diagnosing and Troubleshooting Guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-monitoring-diagnosing-troubleshooting/#the-client-is-receiving-404-messages) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I would expect the `blockBlob.UploadText(data);` to throw if it fails to write the data, isn't this the case? As mentioned in the question,  we generate a new file for each data chunk received, file names are GUIDs so there can never be two similar messages referencing the same file.

Comment: Just done some more investigation, thanks to the link on monitoring and diagnostics. Please see my edits.

Comment: Do you have Storage analytics enabled?

Comment: A couple of thoughts: do you have exception handling in the code that writes the data to the file - one observation is that if the container doesn't exist then blob.uploadtext will fail with a 404. This would obviously then lead to your second job not being able to find the image and would also return a 404. It might also help if you run with Fiddler and check the request / response or alternatively enabled Storage Analytics and see what is written to the logs after the call occurs.

Comment: yes our storage analytics are on but there is no reference to our blob in there. All the log entries for that day were successful and we could see no errors.

Comment: Another angle to investigate is whether it is possible that the web job is running twice on the same object - this could occur if the message is enqueued twice, or if the web job partially completes and then fails etc. Is that possible? When you said you had looked at the logs can you confirm you are able to see the Blob get created, set properties being called and then the delete operation from the web job. It sounded like you were saying that you can't see the Blob in the logs at all - which would imply the job is failing at uploadtext.

Comment: thanks a lot for guiding us Jason, please see my second edit. The problem is definitely within our app processing the message more than once, we are still investigating - the issue is either in our app or in service bus. Storage is definitely off the hook :)